# Node Module command from PHP exec() not working, but working in terminal

Tags: php, node.js

Hi I want to run a node js script.
If I run in terminal `node app.js` it will work.
But if I use

```
$output = shell_exec('node -v 2>&1');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

or

```
$output = shell_exec('node app.js 2>&1');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

I get `node: not found` error
If I run

```
$output = shell_exec('ls');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

It shows the current files in that folder where i have the app.js

Comment: Presumably node is not in the path of the user executing the PHP script

Comment: Maybe you have node installed only for your user, and PHP is running with another user?

Answer (score 0):

As some of the comments have said, the node executable may not be in your PATH. For example, if you used something like [nvm](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to install node, it might not be in the PATH. Try running `whereis node` in your terminal to find out where node is installed, and use shell_exec with the absolute path.

For example, if I run `whereis node` and the output is

```
node: /home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v19.2.0/bin/node
```

I could use shell_exec like this:

```
$output = shell_exec('/home/user/.nvm/versions/node/v19.2.0/bin/node -v 2>&1');
```

Keep in mind that this will not work if your home directory's permissions restrict the web server from accessing its contents.